# HDMI output not working after Suspend in Ubuntu 18.04 on MSI GS65 Stealth Thin

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, suspend, hdmi, msi

After a cold boot HDMI output for an external monitor works fine for a while, however after a power management event like a Suspend, the HDMI output is turned off and will not turn back on.

I see this behaviour with both the Nouveau and the nvidia 390.48 drivers, although it works as expected on Windows. I've applied the latest BIOS (E16Q2IMS.10D) and EC firmware (16Q2EMS1.105), but neither made any difference.

I've dabbled around with `xrandr` but HDMI-1-1 won't come back on even after warm boot, it needs a cold boot to reactive.  Curiously the DisplayPort output works, although I have to use an HDMI dongle for that, which is physically a bit messy.

Does anyone else have this same issue?

Comment: Read `man pm-action` to see what your system does as  part of Suspend/Resume or Hibernate/Wake. What are these "warm boot" and "cold boot" of which you speak? Did you run `pm-is-supported`?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - it did prompt me to look in that direction, however non of the tweaks I tried, such settings for DPMS made any difference. (warm boot is simply rebooting without a full power off, cold boot is power off/on).

Things are much worse since I installed the latest firmware released on 2018/09/12.  Now external monitors are not detected at all when connected to this laptop running Linux, although work fine in Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for a long time, and just solved the issue.

Reboot your laptop, open the BIOS and disable the `Fast Boot` option in the `Boot` section. After rebooting you should be able to get your HDMI back.

Comment: thank you very much you saved me to buy a macbook, thank you again

Answer (score 0):

```
xset -dpms
```

then restart fixed the issue for me --  MSI GS65 + ubuntu 18.04

Comment: What does that command do ?

Comment: `man xset`  :

The -dpms option disables DPMS (Energy Star) features.

Answer (score 0):

Found, that problem was in intel sound driver ?

Somehow it connected to nvidia ?;)

If disable it - no sound, but external monitor working.

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1070069/ubuntu-18-04-msi-gs65-8re-external-monitor-not-working-after-suspend/?offset=3#5421500